# How to stop esc key from stopping redirect

Tags: javascript, ajax, forms, keyboard, submit

Using AJAX to submit an order:

1. user fills out form and clicks submit
2. disable submit button to keep from multiple clicks
3. pop up modal informing that order is being submitted
4. submits form via ajax
5. **if successful, redirects to order confirmation page**
6. if not successful, explains why, hides modal, reactivates submit...etc.

**The problem is**, when they click submit, if they then click escape key, it can stop the redirect, and then the page is just stuck on pending even though the order technically already went through.

**Question:**

How can I keep the user from using the escape key to stopping my redirect?

I don't think the user would even know that's what they're doing, but in my case, the order has already been processed.  Hitting escape simply keeps them from seeing their confirmation page, likely making them assume the order didn't go through.

Is there another/better way to handle this situation?

Comment: You can't.  If the user wants to stop the user agent (e.g. the browser), they can.  Same thing could happen with the "stop" button in the browser.

Comment: Have the page poll the status for the order after an interval so it can retrieve the required redirect without actually sending an order.

Comment: @DaveAnderson - I don't understand.  Can you clarify?

Comment: Maybe notify the user that the order went through before the redirect? That way even if something happens and he doesn't land on the confirmation page he knows the order went through.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what you are trying to do exactly but I'm assuming staying in the page after success destroys your site logic and I'm going to give you some tips

But be aware there is no ultimate solution to this problem,the user can click the stop button on the browser, or he can close the tab all together !

so I'm assuming this is only to prevent user mistakes only

First Way: when the success call back triggers, make a Boolean variable as flag to preserve the success state, now when the user submits again if it's true you can redirect again, or maybe even put a timer that tries to redirect every x seconds for example based on this flag

Second Way:(I'M NOT SURE IF THIS WORKS!) Register a keyboard event for the escape button, and consume the event using event.stopPropagation this might be even browser dependent

Answer (score 0):

Your original submit sends the Ajax request to some web service for fulfilling the order e.g. `/ordersubmit`. The logic in the web service returns the redirect response after a successful order. The response may take some time and the user can cancel the request before the response is received.

Create a new web service e.g `/orderstatus` that checks the order and if it has been successful returns the same redirect response as `/ordersubmit` would. If the order is still pending or has an error return a suitable message body.

The web order page has a timer started after the initial Ajax request to `/ordersubmit`. When the timer expires the page sends a new Ajax request to `/orderstatus` and acts on the response.

If the response isn't the redirect start a new timer and check again. If after three tries the order still isn't complete show a suitable message asking them to contact support.

Comment: How would I know which order to check if it hasn't yet been created (or was created, but didn't pass back an ID, since the script stopped)?

Comment: Generate a unique request reference with the order, if you have a user account include that as part of the reference. If you have .Net maybe use the session id as part of the reference. Anything you can create client side that is unique and can send with the next request and allow you to match it to the original order submission.

Comment: Slightly more complicated would be a quick initial Ajax request to generate an order reference server side that is required by the client before sending the rest of the order.